# How do I print the arrays to the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am unable to print the tipArray and totalArray to the console

```js
var bills = [124, 48, 268]


function calculateTip(amount) {
  var tipArray = []
  var totalArray = []
  if (amount < 50) {
    tipArray.push(bills * .20)
    totalArray.push((bills * .20) + bills)
  } else if (amount >= 50 && amount < 200) {
    tipArray.push(bills * .15)
    totalArray.push((bills * .15) + bills)
  } else {
    tipArray.push(bills * .10)
    totalArray.push((bills * .10) + bills)
  }
  return tipArray, totalArray
}


console.log(calculateTip(bills))
```

I would like to print the tipArray and totalArray to the console

Comment: `bills` is array. You need to loop it

Comment: You can't return more than one value with the `return` statement.

Comment: How would I use a forEach method?

Comment: First of all in your function calculateTip(amount) you defined the variable amount, so you should use amount in the function instead of bills. Secondly, you should use a for loop to iterate through the array. And finally, you can't return more than one value. You can return an array containing the two arrays. I edited my answer, check it.

Comment: Thanks Kadir, I understand what you did now, and it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return more than one value with return. You can however return an array with the two values.

```js
var bills = [124, 48, 268]


function calculateTip(amount) {
  var tipArray = []
  var totalArray = []
  for(i=0;i<amount.length;i++){
  if (amount[i] < 50) {
    tipArray.push(amount[i] * .20)
    totalArray.push((amount[i] * .20) + amount[i])
  } else if (amount[i] >= 50 && amount[i] < 200) {
    tipArray.push(amount[i] * .15)
    totalArray.push((amount[i] * .15) + amount[i])
  } else {
    tipArray.push(amount[i] * .10)
    totalArray.push((amount[i] * .10) + amount[i])
  }
}
   return [tipArray,totalArray]
}

console.log(calculateTip(bills)[0])
console.log(calculateTip(bills)[1])
```

> calculateTip(bills)[0] will return the tipArray and
>   calculateTip(bills)[1] will return the totalArray

By the way, there were other issue with your code, you should loop through the array to iterate through all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Array * constant returns NaN, try to replays `bills * k` with `bills.map(x=>x*k)`